# filtering using regex and returning the matched number

Tags: php, regex

Here i am trynig to filter the specific phone numbers from text using regex. Phone name may have exploits like this.

`4023one345233` should be considered as `40231345233` and then should be filtered.

This code works fine without exploits:

code1:

```
$arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $text, $matches);
$arr=$matches[0];
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $v = strtolower($v);
    if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
    {
        $text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);
    }
}
foreach ($words as $word){

    $pattern = '/^(?=.{8,14})b$\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$^|^2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-49]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|4(?:0[03-9]|2[02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79]|8[0-5789])|5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[0145689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|6(?:0[034689]|2[0-689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}|7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}|76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}|80(?:0\d{6,7}|8\d{7})|500\d{6}|(?:87[123]|9(?:[01]\d|8[0-3]))\d{7}|8(?:4[2-5]|70)\d{7}|70\d{8}|56\d{8}|(?:3[0347]|55)\d{8}|8(?:001111|45464\d)$|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );            
    $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
}
```

From SO help I could reach this code which filters number with exploits as mentioned above.

[http://ideone.com/8UW22U - Link to test](http://ideone.com/8UW22U)

code2:

```
$arrwords = array_flip(array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine'));

$s = "my long STRING with some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233";

$sanitised = array();    
foreach (explode(" ", $s) as $word) {
    $num = strtr(strtolower($word), $arrwords);
    $sanitised[] = is_numeric($num) ? str_repeat("*", strlen($word)) : $word;        
}

echo implode(" ", $sanitised);
```

But as in my first code, I just want to match the pattern after finding the number and then returning `matched pattern`

Here I have tried to port code 2 in code 1.

```
foreach (explode(" ", $s) as $word) {
    $num = strtr(strtolower($word), $arrwords);
    if(is_numeric($num)){ 
         $pattern = 'regex_above';
        preg_match_all($pattern, <$text?????>, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );            
        $this->pushToResultSet($matches);

    }
}
```

can some one help to correct this?

**Note** : Please see, the lenght of origianl number and matched pattern should be same.
Means `4023three345233` should be matched as `****************` not `***********`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to replace a string of numbers (possibly containing written numbers) with asterisks. The number of asterisks must be equal to the number of characters in the string.

In the code below, the regex matches strings that contain 3 to 7 numbers.

```
$s = "123 onetwothree 1two3 one dog";
$new_words = array();
$numbers = array();
$pattern = "#(\d|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine){3,7}#i";
foreach(explode(" ", $s) as $word) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $word, $matches)) {
        $new_words[] = str_repeat("*", strlen($word));
        $numbers[] = $matches[0];
    } else {
        $new_words[] = $word;
    }
}

$new_s = implode(" ", $new_words);
print $new_s . "\n";
print implode(" ", $numbers) . "\n";
```

which gives:

```
*** *********** ***** one dog
123 onetwothree 1two3
```

The regex in your code is extremely long and adding 'zero|one|...' to the regex might not be feasible for you. Another solution could be to:

- get the number of characters of each word in your string: $word_lengths
- replace written numbers with their numerical values. e.g. 'one' becomes '1'
- match with your long regex
- if there is a match, create a string of asterisks according to $word_lengths

Comment: thanks for you answer. Yes I want to convert word digit into number and then filtering it. But my code already doing this. see `code2` which does this correctly. What I need now is to write `code2` to be work as in `code1`. matching the pattern and returning matched pattern